# ASP.NET production websites that are SVN working copies

Tags: asp.net, svn

Is it good practice to have a production (live) asp.net website that is also a working copy to push updates?

Comment: Why the close vote? (I couldnt find a duplicate - if i am wrong i will delete)

Comment: I've done this for web site projects (as apposed to web application projects), since they don't work well with web deploy.

Comment: I have as well, its very convenient, but I worry about it having side affects.  For example, copies of the code and svn passwords existing inside the live web site.

Comment: Does your working copy contain the full source or the "published" web site?

Comment: The working copy is of the development repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general this is considered bad practice primarily because the source control repository contains the *source* whereas the production application contains the *result*.  The two are kept separate for a number of reasons:

- Security.  If your source is on your production server, it's at risk of being viewed.  Maybe this is a problem, maybe it's not.  The safe approach is to just not have the source on the production server.
- Performance.  The result of building the source can be optimized for performance in ways that the source itself generally isn't.  In a .NET application, for example, the production deployment doesn't contain debugging symbols.  This may not be an issue in your particular application, but it's something to consider.
- Multiple Results.  Is your source an actual application, or is it information used to build an application?  Can multiple versions be built?  For example, in a .NET web application, you might have Web.config transforms.  These are used at deploy-time to adjust the result of building the source.  If the source itself is being used as the live application, these deploy-time modifications aren't available.

Others may be able to articulate this much better than I can, but in general it is considered bad practice, yes.  Your particular application may be an exception to any particular reason or may not be meaningfully affected by any particular reason, so I stress the "in general" part.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the layout of your project, there may be some security concerns. For instance, if you have a .txt file with some sensitive information, keep in mind that it will accessible in your site.

Anything in App_Code or any .cs, .vb, .config, etc files will not be served by ASP.NET, so you can put stuff you don't want people seeing there.

Also, for initial loading performance, you should precompile your site via the VS Publish command or the Web Deployment Project addin (assuming you're working with a web site project). You could create an svn branch for the precompiled, deployable code and use that branch on your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use services like http://springloops.io or http://deployhq.com to only push certain folders to a server. That gives you a lot of flexibility in pushing code to deployment.